# Why I'm not the owner of unzipped files?

Tags: 16.04, permissions, nautilus, eclipse, extract

When I try to unzip my file (both with Nautilus and from terminal) I find my files in the destination, but I'm not the owner, and when I import these on Eclipse, it gives me a permission error.
Refer the screenshot below (files have a lock icon).

[image: screenshot of files with lock icon]

How I can unzip them without the lock icon?

Comment: Could you give me the exact commands you used to unzip from the Terminal? and `ls -ahl` on both the zip file and the extracted contents?

Comment: ls -ahl of zip file: `-rw-rw-r--  1 alessandro alessandro 7,9M gen 12 18:40 selenium-java-3.8.1.zip`

ls -ahl of directory: `drwxrwxr-x  3 alessandro alessandro 4,0K gen 12 19:21 selenium-java-3.8.1`

Comment: Is your mount point defined to have a different UID, by any chance? In other words, is the partition containing the zip file mounted with a specific UID?

Comment: did you use sudo to unzip? using sudo will usually make root the owner.